For a symmetric matrix $B$ and following four relevant matrices $P,Q,C,D$, what's the relation between $QP$ and $CDC^{\rm T}$?
Suppose $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix with ${\rm rank}(B)=r$. Then $B$ is equivalent to $\tilde{B}$ in (1), where $I_{r}$ denotes the identity matrix of order $r$. That is, there exist two invertible matrices $P,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $PBQ=\tilde{B}$. On the other hand, $B$ is congruent to $E$ in (1) with $r_{1}+r_{2}=r$. That is, there exists invertible matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $C^{\rm T}BC=E$. Moreover, select $D$ as (1), and then we have $C^{\rm T}BCD=\tilde{B}$. If $B$ is positive semidefinite, then $E=\tilde{B}$ and $D=I_{n}$.
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  \tilde{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
   I_{r} & 0\\ 0 &0
  \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n},
  E = \begin{bmatrix}
   I_{r_{1}} & & \\
   &-I_{r_{2}} &\\
   &&0
  \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n},
  D=\begin{bmatrix}
   I_{r_{1}} & &\\
   &-I_{r_{2}} &\\
   & & I_{n-r}
  \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}.
 \end{equation}
Here comes my question: for any $P,Q,C,D$ satisfying $PBQ=C^{\rm T}BCD=\tilde{B}$, what's the relation between $QP$ and $CDC^{\rm T}$? Or to say the least, just like $CDC^{\rm T}$, is the product $QP$ also symmetric?
For example, consider
\begin{equation*}
  B=\begin{bmatrix}
   -12 & 6 & -2\\
  6 & -3 & 1\\
  -2 & 1 &0
  \end{bmatrix}.
 \end{equation*}
Choose
\begin{equation*}
  P=\begin{bmatrix}
   0& 1&0\\0 &0 &1\\1 & 2 &0
  \end{bmatrix},
  Q=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 &0 &1\\0 &1 &2\\1 &3 &0
  \end{bmatrix},
  C=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 2\\ 1 & 1 & 4\\ 2 &-1 &0
  \end{bmatrix},
  D=\begin{bmatrix}
   1 &&\\&-1&\\&&1
  \end{bmatrix}.
 \end{equation*}
We have
\begin{equation*}
  QP = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 &2&0\\ 
   2&4&1\\
   0&1&3
  \end{bmatrix},
CDC^{\rm T}=\begin{bmatrix}
3&7&1\\7&16&3\\1&3&3
\end{bmatrix}.
 \end{equation*}
When $B$ is of full rank, it is easy to show $QP=CDC^{\rm T}$ since they are both the inverse of $B$. If $r<n$, I have tried a lot of examples, and find $QP$ is always symmetric. However, I still can't give a rigorous proof for the symmetry of $QP$, or the relation between $QP$ and $CDC^{\rm T}$. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.
