For a real symmetric matrix, is the product of two factors of its rank decomposition (right times left) also symmetric?
Recently, I am learning generalized inverse of a matrix. Given a real symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with ${\rm rank}(A)=r$, suppose the rank decomposition of $A$ is given as follows:
$$
 PAQ = \begin{bmatrix}
  I_{r} & 0\\ 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n},
 $$
where $P,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are invertible.
Through several examples, I observed the product $QP$ is always symmetric. Here comes my question: for any real symmetric matrix, is $QP$ also symmetric? Although I have tried a lot, I still can not give a rigorous proof. Any answer will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

$QP$ must be symmetric in the specific case that $r = n$. I suspect that it must also be symmetric in the case that $r = n-1$.

Yes, if $r=n$, then $QP$ equals the inverse of $B$, which is also symmetric.

Neither $PQ$ nor $QP$ is necessarily symmetric. As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \quad 
P = Q = \pmatrix{
1&0&0\\
0&1&1\\0&0&1}.
$$
We find that
$$
QP = PQ = P^2 = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&2\\0&0&1},
$$
which is not symmetric.

Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I find I have not prepared plenty of examples.

@W.J Generating good examples is a skill you pick up. A common incorrect approach for a situation like this is to have a computer generate symmetric matrices at random, e.g. by selecting i.i.d. normally distributed entries. This is a bad idea here since matrices generated like this are invertible with nearly 100% probability. The key, however you're generating examples, is to look for a property to vary that you think might be relevant. In this case, making sure that you try symmetric matrices of different ranks is key.

Thanks again for your detailed instructions. I have tried rank-deficient matrix in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4930822/692201 .  In fact, I generated $A$ by $C^{T}$diag(1,...-1...,0,...)$C$, where $C$ is chosen to be invertible. Your example is succint and efficient. I forgot to choose $C$ as identity matrix. You help me a lot!
